# Drupal account registration

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have installed Drupal 7.42 and am using it with Xampp server with PHP version 5.5.27 and server version 5.6.25. I want to access the Drupal admin page or dashboard but I can't because when I create a new account it asks me to select a username and then asks for my email. I provide both of these and then get a message saying that I should check my mail for further instructions to activate the account.

The problem is I am not getting any such mail even after several attempts. My junk folder too has nothing in it. Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: You say that you can't access admin page, but again you say that "when I create a new account..."..?! You can you create a new account without accessing admin pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See in database the table users and follow this post [Recovering the administrator password](https://www.drupal.org/node/44164)